# Visual Studio 2022: C++ project's output DLL not available to sibling C# project's output assembly

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio 2022, I have a solution containing several C# projects and one C++ project. C# project “Application” builds into a class library (DLL) targeting .NET 7.0. This project depends on the C++ DLL project “Legacy” (built without /CLI) also in the solution. However, when I build the solution, the Legacy DLL does not get copied into Application’s output folder (nor the main .exe project’s output folder), and so when the overall program is run, it crashes when it realises it cannot find Legacy.dll.

The Legacy project shows up in the dependency list of Application with a little yellow warning triangle, which is probably a significant clue. Removing this dependency and re-adding it makes no difference. Restarting VS make no difference.

If I manually copy Legacy.dll into the same folder as Application.dll, it all runs fine, but this is not an acceptable solution. The assemblies of other dependent projects (all C#) do get copied over during the solution build, and recognised at runtime.

I found out the following when researching the cause of the yellow warning triangle:

- although building from within the VS IDE succeeds with no errors, building using “dotnet build -c Debug” from the Package Manager Console fails, with error MSB4019: The imported project “D:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props” was not found in the .vcxproj file (from this line: <Import project=“$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props” />).
- error MSB4019 seems to be caused by the macro $(VCTargetsPath) not being defined. The missing file does exist (in my case in D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC\v170).
- if I open the properties dialog for the C++ project, and click on a property that can use macros, and examine which macros are defined, $(VCTargetsPath) is correctly defined as D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC\v170. So the macro definition seems to exist, but somehow gets reset during a build (at least, when building from the Package Manager Console).

Ideally, I’d like the yellow warning triangle to go away, AND the C++ DLL to be copied to the correct location during build from the VS IDE.

Comment: **when the overall program is run,it crashes**  Is the program started by Visual Studio Debugger or .exe file?

Comment: Visual Studio Debugger. "Crashes" in this case means that it throws an exception: it cannot find Legacy.dll. I expect the same problem would occur if I ran the program outside of a debugger; the debugger is running the .exe from the expected folder.

Comment: In my test, C# project can copy C++ dlls. Try repairing Visual Studio or recreating the project and dll.

Comment: C# and C++ have different schemes to ensure all executable files are available for debugging.  C++ builds to a shared folder in the solution directory, C# relies on being able to find the dependencies from the metadata and copy everything to the .exe project's build directory.  That's what fails here, the C++ project does not produce a managed dll so it isn't listed as a dependency.  You have to help, either with xcopy in a post-build event or by adding the C++ dll to the C# project so it can be explicitly copied (Copy if Newer).

Comment: Thank you, @HansPassant. I can make this work. Can you give any advice regarding using  an MSBuild project property across projects? I could improve my post-build script if I could use a property, defining the output path of the C++ dll, from within the C# project that needs to copy it.